# Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package

Tags: component, joomla-api, joomla-1.5, restful-api

I'm looking for an extension to serve my Joomla 1.5 websites contents as REST, after some search I've found https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rest-api/ component,  but there is no specification which version is for  my joomla 1.5,  when I clicked on Get REST API v1.6.2 redirect me to another page which there are several version of com_api, I downloaded and tested com_api_v1.5.1.zip, com_api_v1.6.2.zip , com_api_v2.2.zip, and try to install them via admin extension manager on `administrator/index.php?option=com_installer` but there weren't any success to install and faced with **Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package.** , my question is which version is compatible with joomla 1.5 and why I faced with this error while I try to install rest api ?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding each zip install file and examining the .xml file will tell you the minimum version of Joomla the install file is designed for.

Look for a line similar to the following example which shows, in this case, that the install file is suitable for Joomla 1.5:

```
<install version="1.5" type="plugin" group="system" method="upgrade">
```

As you probably already know [Joomla 1.5 is end of life since 2012](https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla!_CMS_versions) and migrating to the latest version will probably make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you for replying, is there any plugin or component which return data as json ? ( something like REST API) ?